# There is a pending suggested edit in the queue message comes in a white page

Tags: bug, suggested-edits

I have seen this behavior lately when I go to edit a question if it is editing by some one else the white page coming with the message saying "There is a pending suggested edit in the queue, try again in a few minutes.". But the page coming with this message was different with an ajax message before as I can remember. Is this normal?